# How to loop through a list of values and copy and paste them in PyAutoGui?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, browser-automation

So I will have a list of values like 34232,23111, etc... I have a form that looks like the following:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe7kn.png)

User has to "Select a Field" which is a dropdown, which he will then have to paste a value from that list into the "Value" Field, select "Or" from the "Join" dropdown. Whenever a value is selected in the "Join", a new entry appears below like the following:
[New entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVAAy.png)

Right now, I am doing this manually which is tedious and time consuming. How would I automate this with PyAutoGui? Is it possible? I would have to get the coordinates of the mouse for every action, but they will be different every time a new entry is added.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you ask can be answered by looking into the [pyautogui docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The functions you are interested in are `locateOnScreen`, `click` and `write`.